# Proof of expenses for a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I am going to Europe on vacation. The trip has been paid for entirely by my parents who will be supporting me through the duration of the trip. 
How do I fill in the proof of funds part of the visa application form? If Im being supported by my parents do I need to attach their bank statements?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/documents.html), your parents can sign an *official affidavit of support*, and they would be responsible for financially supporting your trip.

> If you don't have a bank account or the balance is not enough to take
>   care of your expenses, you must ask your friends/relatives to sign an
>   "official affidavit of support", available at the local Alien's office
>   in their place of residence. You must bring the original of this
>   affidavit when applying for your visa.

Comment: The "official affidavit of support" is used for the friends or relatives being visited -- that is, Schengen residents -- to indicate that they will support the traveler.  Presumably Sarah's parents do not live in the Schengen area, and so they do not have a "local Aliens' office in their place of residence."  Consequently, Sarah should probably include her parents' bank statements in her application.  The application requirements list on the German web site is rather poor, given that it lists specific documents rather than explaining what the documents are supposed to show.